# How to extract variable with jquery in php from json?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I wish to extract one variable by one variable from my json file. My goal is to use this variable in php, to be able to do mysql query for exemple.

So my json file is here: `pages/getRank-classic.php?idstart=0`

```
[
    {"rank":1,"id":"111","site_name":"test1","site_vip":"No","boost":"0","site_banner":"test.png","site_banner_wallrank":"","site_pointstotaux":"5044","site_motclef1":"Pvp\/Fac","site_motclef2":"Skyblock","site_motclef3":"Cr\u00e9atif","site_motclef4":"Hunger-Games","site_motclef5":"SKywars\/Mini-Gam","site_presentationvideo":"3TGjebmNOfs"},
    {"rank":2,"id":"222","site_name":"test2","site_vip":"No","boost":"0","site_banner":"test.jpg","site_banner_wallrank":"","site_pointstotaux":"4114","site_motclef1":"hunger","site_motclef2":"games","site_motclef3":"pvp","site_motclef4":"survival","site_motclef5":null,"site_presentationvideo":"3TGjebmNOfs"}
]
```

I am trying to use it in include like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/pages/getRank-classic.php?idstart=0',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(test) {
        alert(test.id);
        alert(test.rank);
    }
});
</script>
```

So how I can do it please?

Comment: `$myvar = json_decode($_REQUEST['yourvar']);`

Comment: I finally used php like that =>
<?php

$jsonlink = '/pages/getRank-classic.php?idstart=0';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonlink);

$link = mysql_connect('sql.n1-servers.fr', 'www-top-mc', 'cd06bc5eprivate');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('www-top-minecraft-serveurs', $link);

$result = json_decode($json);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {

 mysql_query("UPDATE `www-top-minecraft-serveurs`.`sites` SET `site_rank` = '$value->rank' WHERE `sites`.`site_id` = '$value->id'");
    }
    mysql_close;
}

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used php like that =>

```
<?php

$jsonlink = '/pages/getRank-classic.php?idstart=0';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonlink);

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'database', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database', $link);

$result = json_decode($json);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE `database`.`sites` SET `site_rank` = '$value->rank' WHERE `sites`.`site_id` = '$value->id'");
    }
    mysql_close;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an array of json, you need to specify the index too.

```
test[0].id
```

Also you can iterate through the object using this way,

```
    var data = [{
    "rank": 1,
    "id": "111",
    "site_name": "test1",
    "site_vip": "No",
    "boost": "0",
    "site_banner": "test.png",
    "site_banner_wallrank": "",
    "site_pointstotaux": "5044",
    "site_motclef1": "Pvp/Fac",
    "site_motclef2": "Skyblock",
    "site_motclef3": "Cr\u00e9atif",
    "site_motclef4": "Hunger-Games",
    "site_motclef5": "SKywars/Mini-Gam",
    "site_presentationvideo": "3TGjebmNOfs"
}, {
    "rank": 2,
    "id": "222",
    "site_name": "test2",
    "site_vip": "No",
    "boost": "0",
    "site_banner": "test.jpg",
    "site_banner_wallrank": "",
    "site_pointstotaux": "4114",
    "site_motclef1": "hunger",
    "site_motclef2": "games",
    "site_motclef3": "pvp",
    "site_motclef4": "survival",
    "site_motclef5": null,
    "site_presentationvideo": "3TGjebmNOfs"
    }];

    $(data).each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
```

You can fetch the json using the ajax, then in the success event, put this code like,

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: '/pages/getRank-classic.php?idstart=0',
data: data,
cache: false,
success: function(test) {
    $(test).each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use it with a json output with more than those 2 exemples.

And how I use it as variable in php ?